# How can I connect Flink to Druid?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, druid

I am trying to connect Flink to Druid.

However, I do not know how to do it correctly.

In this [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html), “bootstrap.servers” is set to be “localhost:9092".

Does this means I can directly connect using [Apache Kafka ingestion](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html), because the sample supervisor spec sets below?

```
    "consumerProperties": {
      "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
    },
```

Do I need to run Kafka other than Flink? Or should I do other things to connect Flink to Druid?

Answer (score 0):

you can connect Flink to Druid via Tranquility https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility